# SQL Server T-SQL query to add to a column if query returns resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop, iterator

Ok so I'm trying to tie two queries together through a cursor.

I create a temp table for name (`varchar`) and count (`int`).

The first query grabs a name and a versionnumber, if that versionnumber = a certain version it adds the name (`varchar`) and a `1` (`int`) to the temp table.

Next I want to have a different query look for a specific privileged for the same name as the first query, if that privilege = a certain privilege then add another 1 to the count column of the temp table.

Thus leaving me with a record in the table with a name and a 2 in the count column.

What I have so far is this:

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable
(
    name varchar(10)
    acount int
)

DECLARE @name nvarchar(10)
DECLARE @acount int
SET @acount = 0

DECLARE name_cursor CURSOR FOR
     SELECT DISTINCT NAME 
     FROM atable

OPEN name_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM name_cursor INTO @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #temptable (name, acount)

    WHILE(SELECT DISTINCT name, version
          FROM atable
          WHERE version = 'specificversion') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @acount = @acount + 1
    END

    WHILE(SELECT DISTINCT name, priviledge
          FROM atable
          WHERE priviledge = 'specifiedpriviledge') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @acount = @acount + 1
    END

    SELECT @name, @acount
END

CLOSE name_cursor
DEALLOCATE name_cursor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess at your table structure and desired result a bit, but I don't think you need a cursor here. Here's what I tried:

```
--Test rig
create table #atable
(
name varchar(10),
versionnum varchar(10),
privilege varchar(10)
)

insert into #atable (name, versionnum, privilege)
values
('Tim', 'A', 'Level 1'),
('Tim', 'B', 'Level 2'),
('Charles', 'A', 'Level 1'),
('Alex', 'C', 'Level 2')
--End Test Rig

CREATE TABLE #temptable
(
  name varchar(10),
  acount int
)

insert into #temptable (name, acount)
select distinct name, 0 from #atable

update #temptable
set acount = acount+1
where #temptable.name in (select name from #atable where #atable.versionnum = 'A')

update #temptable
set acount = acount+1
where #temptable.name in (select name from #atable where #atable.privilege = 'Level 2')

select * from #atable
select * from #temptable

drop table #temptable
drop table #atable
```

This got me

```
Alex   1
Charles   1
Tim   2
```

Which is what I assume you wanted. Tim has an entry with a Version of A and also has an entry with a Privilege of Level 2, even though they're different entries. Charles has one with Version A, and Alex has one with a Privilege of Level 2. Is that about what you were looking for?

Comment: Also note, if you had a 3rd entry for Tim with both Version A and Privilege Level 2 he'd come out with 4 instead of 3 since it would be double counted. But then I think the begs the question what you're looking for. If you wanted 3 there, you'd need to alter the second update statement to say "Where Privilege = Level 2 and Versionnum <> 'A'" to remove any double counting

Comment: I think this might work, Ya i definitely dont want to do any double counting from each of the separate queries. I basically want to have the ability to add in a multitude of queries each one looking at a different value in a certain column, if that value meets a criteria for that query then add 1 to the count and then either append the count variable and wait till the end to add the count to the temptable or append the temptable on the spot after each query. Thanks, ill test this all out!

Comment: Depending on how many criteria you wanted to do, i might have an idea for using a loop to cut down the update statements... might have to experiment. But hopefully that gives you what you need to continue!